# append string to every line starting from second

Tags: perl, append, lines

I have an file as shown

```
    ford
    speed ....
    hyundai
    speed ...
    ferrari
    speed ....
    BMW
    Merc
    lambo
    speed ...
```

I want to search for "speed" in every alternate line staring from 2nd, and if not found i want to append "speed\n".
i.e. i want my output to be

```
        ford
        speed ....
        hyundai
        speed ...
        ferrari
        speed ....
        BMW
        speed
        Merc
        speed
        lambo
        speed ...
```

Is there any oneliner that can be used for the above problem like the one used to append to each line like

```
perl -ple 's/^/speed/' filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stick with `perl -pe` in this case, however we have to output extra "speed" line when both:

- odd number of lines has been printed
- current one is not /speed/

So... ($odd = (number of lines **printed** so far) % 2)

```
perl -pe 'next if ($odd ^= 1 or /^\s*speed/); print "speed\n"; $odd ^= 1; '
```

**UPDATE:** Due to how -n/-p works, the last line in file was not processed correctly. So I added an END block for that. "If we stopped at odd line, append speed".

```
perl -ple 'chomp; next if ($odd ^= 1 or /^speed/); print "speed"; $odd ^= 1; END { print "speed" if $odd }'
```

Though it's a line-and-a-halfer and not one-liner now =)

Comment: it works fine for the above example.. But what if speed is not present after 'lambo'. if thats not present then i want it to print speed after that as well.

Comment: Aha, the last line. I missed that case. Should be smth like `END{ print "speed" if $odd }`, but then the `$.++` variant is shorter.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -plne 'if($.%2==0){unless(/speed/) {print "speed";$.++;}}' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
ford
speed ....
hyundai
speed ...
ferrari
speed ....
BMW
Merc
lambo
speed ...
> perl -plne 'if($.%2==0){unless(/speed/) {print "speed";$.++;}}' temp
ford
speed ....
hyundai
speed ...
ferrari
speed ....
BMW
speed
Merc
speed
lambo
speed ...
>
```

Comment: I have a very-very basic question. If you try to print the value of `$.` in your above one-liner the first value it prints is `8(Merc)` and now you do `$.++` so that  value becomes `9` and than due to loop it becomes `10`. If we look at the current file there are only `10lines` in it so the value of `$.==10` means `speed` in our current file. So. does perl makes a local copy of complete file in memory and than `simaltaneously` writes and than reads that `modified file` on next iteration?

Comment: My basic question is how we are able to iterate more lines than there are in the `temp file` until and unless it(local copy) is simaltaneously modifies also.

Comment: thank you so much @sarathi .. it works fine for me. But this doesnt print the value if speed is not present at the end after 'lambo'

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea:

```
perl -ne 'print "speed\n" if ( $v = !m/^\s*speed\b/ and $no_speed ); print; $no_speed = $v'
```

Answer (score -1):

The line number is availabel in `$.`

so if you neeed to perform some action on every second line in a one liner you could do something like:

```
perl -ple 's/^/speed/ if $. % 2 == 0' filename
```

Interpreting the result of the % operator direclty as a boolean, this can be reduced to:

```
perl -ple 's/^/speed// if !($. % 2)' filename
```

Read [the perlvar manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles) for the documentation about `$.`

Comment: But this prints in each alternative lines.. It doesnt check if there is speed in the alternative line.

Comment: Also, it does not adjust to the fact that if a speed line is missing, the line count should toggle between odd/even.